# Bounding a simple expression

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Hi does anyone know what constant $C$ I could put here to make this inequality correct : for $a\in [0,1] $
$$ a^{1/5}+a^{4/21} \leq Ca^{4/21} $$

Comment: This cannot hold for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, just take $a\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry say  $a\in [0,1]$

Comment: @user128470 We show this, we don't even need ([tag:limits]), whose ([tag:epsilon-delta]) definition might be too advanced for high school students.  Just some simple ([tag:inequalities]) will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Under the assumption $0\leq a\leq 1$)
Rearranging, we find
$$
a^{1/105}\leq C-1,
$$
so we clearly need $C\geq 1$. On the other hand, the left hand side is increasing and assumes its maximum in $a=1$, hence $C=2$ is okay.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your answer, would i be right in saying if $a\leq 2^{1/2}$ then $C=3$ would work by very similar working:)

Answer (score 0):

(This answers the [original version](//math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2768405/1) of the question.  For the current version, see the alternative answer.)

This is impossible.

- For any $C > 1$,
  $$a^{1/5}+a^{4/21} \leq Ca^{4/21} \iff a^{1/105} \le a^{1/5-4/21} \leq C-1,$$
  so any $a > (C-1)^{105}$ violates the above inequality.
- For any $C \le 1$,
  $$a^{1/5}+a^{4/21} \leq Ca^{4/21} \le a^{4/21} \iff a^{1/5} \le 0,$$
  so any $a > 0$ violates the above inequality.